# Can you tell what enemies your soldiers would be able to see/fire on before moving?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

When moving, XCOM provides a helpful blue line indicating what path your soldier will take.  This is extremely helpful to see BEFORE you move, in situations like:

1. When you're trying to sneak up on an enemy, but your soldier is going to jump through a glass window, you know, just because
2. When the game is glitching out and can't tell what square your mouse is over and wants to move you down a level

Is there any similar indicator of which enemies will be in view from a potential destination square?  Examples of situations where it is frustrating not to have one:

1. You move in to shoot at a far-off enemy... and find out you haven't moved in far enough
2. There's an object sorta in the way between you and the potential target... and you find out that, actually, the game thinks it's completely in the way
3. The game is glitching out (ESPECIALLY bad when you're climbing on top of the enemy ships) and thinks you can't see an enemy who's two squares away because they're up a tiny slope.

Comment: 2.When the game is glitching out and can't tell what square your mouse is over and wants to move you down a level... try going up or down with the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 8):

Your third example is a bug, I believe.  I've run into it, it's super annoying (and occasionally devastating).

Unfortunately, I have never seen anything from the UI/options that would help in either situation #1 or #2.  About the only thing you can do in these situations is to move to the closest possible cover within the blue, and then if you can't take the shot you want, either go to overwatch or possibly re-position as part of the dash with the goal of moving into a more advantageous position on the following turn.  The cover thing is especially vexing, I feel your pain there.  The game is forcing you to eyeball it; unfortunately, cover is at high enough level of abstraction such that eyeballing it is not always possible.

Note that Assaults, once leveled, are really good to use in these situations. You can move to wherever you think is best in the blue radius and then if you're unsatisfied with the results you can pop Run n Gun and advance further and then shoot (and you can even do Rapid Fire after doing a run and gun, it's quite a potent combo).